# HELP for diagnosis: Young pepper leaves are curling inward with no pests evident

Tags: identification, diagnosis, diseases

[image]

I’ve been growing this plant hydroponically for about 1 month now and the new growth and some older leaves are curling inward. I suspected that it might be due to insects but there seems to be no trace or evidence of it. Just to make sure I sprayed a self-formulated insecticide consisting of oil, water and dish soap for about 2 times. I’m continuously spraying until now, but i cant help but worry for it.

Comment: The plant also started to flower, and this happened at the same time the leaves started to curl.

Comment: There are kind of like white circle spots on the leaves now, and a yellow discolouration on one of the base of the leaves